# A 4 digits number is formed using 2,3,5,7 and 9 without repeat

Tags: permutations, combinations

A 4 digits number is formed using 2,3,5,7 and 9 without repeat. How many 4 digit numbers are there if each number has a remainder of 2 when divided either by 3 or 5?

As  i know, 2,3,5,7 and 9 is combination(No repetition) as order does not matter. But I don't understand the part of each number has remainder of 2 when divided either by 3 or 5.

Answer (score 3):

A number has remainder $2$ on division by $5$ if and only if the last digit is either a $2$ or a $7$.

A number has remainder $2$ on division by $3$ if and only if the sum of the digits has remainder $2$ on division by $3$.

The sum of all $5$ digits is $26$, which has remainder $2$ on division by $3$. If we do not use one of the digits and still want remainder $2$, the digit we do not use must be $3$ or $9$.

So the problem is saying that (i) our number ends in $2$ or $7$ and (ii) our number uses all the digits except one of $3$ or $9$.

Probably you can now do the counting. When we count four-digit numbers, the order very much matters.

Comment: Hi thanks! I have found this solution not sure whether it is correct, 5!/(5-1)!=> 5!/4! => 4.

Comment: You are welcome. Here is one way to count. (1) Leave out $3$. We have $2$ choices for last digit, for each we have $3$ choices for first digit, $2$ choices for second, total $12$. (2) Leave out $9$, the same. So total $24$.

Comment: Hi thanks again! How come is it 2 choices for the last digit? the first digit taken 1 choice is 3, and 2nd is 2 choice and 3rd is 1 choice?

Comment: It was explained in the answer. The remainder on division by $5$  is $2$. So the last digit must be a $2$ or a $7$, two choices.

Comment: I hope the logic of the counting is now clear. Instead of splitting into $2$ cases, we could have said there are $2$ ways to choose which of $3$ or $9$ we leave out. Then we get $(2)(2)(3)(2)$.